# 413 error with Kubernetes and Nginx ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I'm trying to change the `client_max_body_size` value, so my NGINX ingress will not return the HTTP 413 Content Too Large error (as seen in the logs).

I've tested a few solutions.
Here is my config map:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
data:
  proxy-connect-timeout: "15"
  proxy-read-timeout: "600"
  proxy-send-timeout: "600"
  proxy-body-size: "8m"
  hsts-include-subdomains: "false"
  body-size: "64m"
  server-name-hash-bucket-size: "256"
  client-max-body-size: "50m"
metadata:
  name: nginx-configuration
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  labels:
    app: ingress-nginx
```

These changes had no effect at all: in NGINX controller's log I can see the information about reloading the config map, but the values in `nginx.conf` are the same:

```
$ cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep client_max                                                                                                       
                            client_max_body_size                    "8m";
                            client_max_body_size                    "1m";
                            client_max_body_size                    "1m";
                            client_max_body_size                    "1m";
                            client_max_body_size                    "1m";
                            client_max_body_size                    "1m";
                            client_max_body_size                    "1m";
                            client_max_body_size                    "1m";
                            client_max_body_size                    "1m";
                            client_max_body_size                    "1m";
                            client_max_body_size                    "1m";
                            client_max_body_size                    "1m";
                            client_max_body_size                    "1m";
```

My `nginx-controller` config uses this image:
`quay.io/kubernetes-ingress-controller/nginx-ingress-controller:0.13.0`

How can I force NGINX to change this setting? I need to change it globally, for all my ingresses.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use the [annotation](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md#custom-max-body-size) `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size` to set the max-body-size option right in your Ingress object instead of changing a base ConfigMap.

Here is the example of usage:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-app
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "50m"
...
```

Comment: I wanted to set it globally, but actually this approach is better as I have my yaml files within the project repository. So it won't be lost. Thanks.

Comment: So the `client-max-body-size` config line can be removed entirely from the `metadata.annotations` ?

Comment: @payne it depends. refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67923692/1086907. If the body is too big, `client-max-body-size` is required to improve the performance. See [Annotations: Client Body Buffer Size](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#client-body-buffer-size)

Comment: `kubectl patch ingress my-ingress -p '{"metadata": {"annotations": {"nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size": "0"}}}'`

Comment: For me it was `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size`

Answer (score 32):

There is confusion here about whether the correct annotation is `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size` or `nginx.org/client-max-body-size`.  The answer is that it might be either!

In the unassailable wisdom of everyone involved, there are two different "NGINX ingresses" in the world.  It's hard to tell which you are running, and Google Search is useless at differentiating here (but what's new).

If you are using the official NGINX Ingress, the correct annotation is here: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/

If you are using the official Kubernetes Ingress based on NGINX, the correct annotation is this: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#custom-max-body-size

If the Docker image name of your ingress implementation is `k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller` then you're using the official Kubernetes version.  By elimination, you can determine if you're using the NGINX implementation.

I hope everyone who contributed to this confusing state has a very bad day.  The rest of you... stay cheery!

Comment: This comment made my day at the end :D

Comment: The part about figuring out which version I had running finally helped me!

Comment: More info and comparison of two Nginx ingresses can be found in [Nginx blog](https://www.nginx.com/blog/guide-to-choosing-ingress-controller-part-4-nginx-ingress-controller-options/).

Comment: Thank you @aaron , this works like a charm. Pretty much everything else I tried didn't work. And its super confusing why the  proxy-body-size isn't found on main nginx website documentation. Very well written !

Answer (score 17):

To set it globally, this [configmap.md](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap.md#proxy-body-size) documentation might be helpful. Turns out the variable to set is `proxy-body-size`, not `client-max-body-size`.

When you deploy the helm chart, you can set `--set-string controller.config.proxy-body-size="4m"`.

Answer (score 10):

Maybe some people got stuck here recently. We just made out that the annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size` is not longer being applied and the correct one would be:

```
  annotations:
    nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "999m"
```

Hope this helps to others.

Comment: By the way, those two annotations for two different nginx ingress controllers. The domain in the prefix is a good reference.

Comment: @Draculater indeed. The problem is that google search sends people to this post and I thought (maybe wrong) that, however this is not the correct question, this response can shorten their search for a solution.

Comment: this one is the right one!

Answer (score 6):

Update:

I have been experiencing the same problem and no solutions were working. After reading through countless blogs and docs that all had the same suggested solution I found that they have changed the naming convention.

It is no longer denoted by "proxy-body-size" or this just never works for me.

link below shows that the correct configmap variable to use is "client-max-body-size"

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/global-configuration/configmap-resource/

Comment: For those reading, this comment applies when using the NGINX-issued ingress controller. If you are using the Kubernetes-issued NGINX controller the property name is still `proxy-body-size`. You can tell this by the annotation key which will be `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/xxxxx` for Kubernetes-issued rather than `nginx.org/xxxxx` which is NGINX-issued.

Comment: I encourage the folks at Nginx and Kubernetes to get together and develop a common spec

Answer (score 3):

you can always make a global change and disable it at all

```
kubectl -n ingress-nginx patch configmap \
nginx-configuration -p '{"data": {"proxy-body-size": "0"}}'
```

or set to 5tb

```
kubectl -n ingress-nginx patch configmap \
nginx-configuration -p '{"data": {"proxy-body-size": "5tb"}}'
```

Answer (score 1):

I have tried both proxy-body-size and client-max-body-size on the configmap and did a rolling restart of the nginx controller pods and when I grep the nginx.conf file in the pod it returns the default 1m.  I am trying to do this within Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS).  I'm working with someone from their support.  They said its not on them since it appears to be a nginx config issue.

The weird hting is we had other clusters in Azure that this wasnt an issue on until we discovered this with some of the newer deployments.  The initial fix they came up with is what is in this thread but it just refuses to change.

Below is my configmap:

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
data:
  client-max-body-size: 0m
  proxy-connect-timeout: 10s
  proxy-read-timeout: 10s
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    control-plane.alpha.kubernetes.io/leader: '{"holderIdentity":"nginx-nginx-ingress-controller-7b9bff87b8-vxv8q","leaseDurationSeconds":30,"acquireTime":"2020-03-10T20:52:06Z","renewTime":"2020-03-10T20:53:21Z","leaderTransitions":1}'
  creationTimestamp: "2020-03-10T18:34:01Z"
  name: ingress-controller-leader-nginx
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  resourceVersion: "23928"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/ingress-nginx/configmaps/ingress-controller-leader-nginx
  uid: b68a2143-62fd-11ea-ab45-d67902848a80
```

After issuing a rolling restart:
kubectl rollout restart deployment/nginx-nginx-ingress-controller -n ingress-nginx

Grepping the nginx ingress controller pod to query the value now reveals:

```
kubectl exec -n ingress-nginx nginx-nginx-ingress-controller-7b9bff87b8-p4ppw cat nginx.conf | grep client_max_body_size
            client_max_body_size                    1m;
            client_max_body_size                    1m;
            client_max_body_size                    1m;
            client_max_body_size                    1m;
            client_max_body_size                    21m;
```

Doesnt matter where I try to change it.  On the configmap for global or the Ingress route specifically.......this value above never changes.

Comment: I can confirm this, we are running in exactly the same problem. AKS version 1.18.4.

Comment: It seems adding `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "50m"` annotation on ingress updates the "client_max_body_size" value on the nginx controller config file.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to fix it by redeploying the nginx-ingress controller after modifying the configmap.

```
kubectl patch deployment your_deployment -p "{\"spec\": {\"template\": {\"metadata\": { \"labels\": {  \"redeploy\": \"$(date +%s)\"}}}}}"
```