# How to change nginx config and restart it using IBM Kubernetes ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, ibm-cloud, kubernetes-ingress

I want to change nginx client_max_body_size using Kubernetes ingress annotations.

My ingress yaml file is like this:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-custom-server-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "10m"
spec:
...
```

I only added the line `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: "10m"`. As saing in here [413 error with Kubernetes and Nginx ingress controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918313/413-error-with-kubernetes-and-nginx-ingress-controller)

Then, I tried to apply using:

```
kubectl diff -f my-custom-ingress.yaml
kubectl apply -f my-custom-ingress.yaml
```

The problem is that this change is not being applied. Checking the nginx.conf file it is still the old 2M value.

```
user@user:~/git/my-custom-server$ kubectl exec -it -n kube-system pod/public-<xxx>-alb1-<yyy> -- cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf | grep client_max 
Defaulting container name to nginx-ingress.
  client_max_body_size 2M;
```

I get the pod name using `kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep alb`  as stated here https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-ingress_health

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system | grep alb
public-<xxx>-alb1-<yyy>   4/4     Running   0          136d
```

I'm very new to Kubernetes and apparently, IBM's one is a little different. I don't know why it does not create an ingress pod in my namespace. I'm 99% sure that this is the right one because it has no other. I don't know if I should restart differently and the `136d` goes back to `0d` when done correctly.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

**Edit** - more info

I found that there is an ingress named alb-default-server

```
$ kubectl get ingress --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME           
default       my-custom-server-ingress
kube-system   alb-default-server
```

After editing and adding an annotation `ingress.bluemix.net/client-max-body-size: size=10m`, nothing changed again. Ref: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/bluemix_stage/containers/cs_annotations.html

```
$ kubectl edit ingress alb-default-server -n kube-system
```

```
 annotations:
   ingress.bluemix.net/client-max-body-size: size=<size>
```

Comment: Hello, could you tell how exactly have you installed your `nginx-ingress`? Also there is a documentation about `Ingress` in general on IBM Cloud: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-ingress-about .

Comment: Hello @dawid It was a long time ago, but I don't remember having to install anything. I just created the my-ingress.yaml file (the first code in my post) without the proxy-body-size annotation and ran kubectl apply. I followed this article [link](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/blog/how-to-use-the-ingress-application-load-balancer-to-expose-an-app-outside-a-kubernetes-cluster)
Apparently, the IBM Kubernetes has some external ingress running in the kube-system namespace using nginx. And I should change this configuration, but I don't know how to make the annotation change to be applied.