# Ingress nginx: 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, ingress-nginx

I use ingress-nginx with Helm Chart. I used to have the problem, that when I would upload a file ZIP (400MB) that I would get the error 413 Request Entity Too Large nginx.

So I changed the proxy-body-size value in my values.yaml file to 800m

values:

```
ingress:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 800m
```

but it's not working. I try to upload file image 10MB, It's still well working.

How can I fix it?

Thank for your support.

Answer (score 2):

The annotation `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size` is not longer being applied and the correct one would be:

annotations:

```
nginx.org/client-max-body-size: "800m"
```

Refer to this [link](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/global-configuration/configmap-resource/)  and [Stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918313/413-error-with-kubernetes-and-nginx-ingress-controller/67923692#67923692) for more information.